# CSS Display flex can't change to display: block

Tags: html, css, woocommerce, styles, checkout

I've searching to fix a line of my css code on WooCommerce Checkout page but I have an issue.

On the website https://freecal.fr/checkout/ (add 1 BBQ sauce to be able to see the checkout with a product https://freecal.fr/product/sauce-barbecue/)

I can't seem to be able to switch the li style of my shipping methods (

under "Expédition" when inspect code)
It's stuck on display:flex when I want display:block (css line 1482), even when I change the code on CSS.

What I Have : https://gyazo.com/a4cf9c867f89f540bbd0597f6c76c0f4

What I Want : https://gyazo.com/3f97f8477ba7330c4a99751df7d10601

Sorry if you don't understand what i'm saying, struggling a bit to explain my situation :(
Looking forwards for any helpers.
Cheers

Comment: where is your code?
i thing you can add `white-space: nowrap;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this

```
<li style="flex-direction:column; align-items: flex-start;">
  <div style="display:flex;">
      <input/>
      <label>...<label>
  </div>
  <button>Choisir un point de retrait</button>
  .......
</li>
```

Comment: I got an idea with your comment,
I add a display:block on the style above on the woocommerce css directly.
Thx